# How to create an overlay the shows a Progress Spinner that can go on top of all windows?

Tags: android

I come from iOS background where I can display new views stuff on top of everything easily.  In android, it doesn't seem as straight forward because each Activity has a layout already defined. So, if I wanted to create a loading view (spinner in the middle), adding a new Layout inside the original layout would mess things up.

Is there any way to do this?

I also tried use a dialogFragment and customizing the dialog, but it always shows the space where a title of the dialog is shown.  I'm not sure how to get rid of this, so there must be some universal way for apps to do this.

Comment: Which type of UI u want..can u please show some image or snap shot?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preferences to flag a value true, and in each each Activity's onResume, you can check for that value. If that value is true, then you can start an activity in a new thread which has just a spinner and a transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following workaround:

Use a FrameLayout as your main layout. Define your UI as the first child (or just not the top frame), then define your spinner in the top. When you want to hide the spinner, just setVisible(View.GONE).